# Date of a selection of rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question that is: Capturing the latest date from a set of specific rows in MySQL.

For example: suppose I have a Purchasing table with id, client id, and date of purchase.

[image]

If I make a selection based on the client id = 1, I must capture the purchase for the id = 2.

Comment: update you question and add the expected  result ....as data not words

Comment: SELECT Id, `client id`, MAX(`date of purchase`)
FROM table where `client id`=1 
GROUP BY `client id`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
SELECT Id, `client id`, MAX(`date of purchase`)
FROM your_db
GROUP BY `client id`
```

Also if you just want to return 1 row then

```
SELECT Id, `client id`, MAX(`date of purchase`)
FROM your_db
WHERE `client id` = 1
```

Comment: The Id column is not an aggregate. This query would not run on other databases or even on MySQL running in strict mode.

Comment: So so. In fact, I wanted to be able to choose the client id via procedure. That is, my "GROUP BY client_id" would be "where client_id = id". But this helped me a lot with the answer!!! Tank you

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats correct for this example Id doesn't actually need to be in there other than it can be a ref. For Strict mysql Tim's answer will work better. For different database thats a question dependant on the DB as there are many ways to skin a cat

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to join to a subquery which finds the latest purchase dates for each client.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT client_id, MAX(purchase_date) AS max_purchase_date
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY client_id
) t2
    ON t1.client_id     = t2.client_id AND
       t1.purchase_date = t2.max_purchase_date
-- WHERE client_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, client_id, DATE_OF_PURCHASE 
FROM purchasing 
GROUP BY DATE_OF_PURCHASE 
HAVING MAX(DATE_OF_PURCHASE)
```

Try above code.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entire row, you can do this in several ways, but think "filtering" rather than "aggregation":

```
select t.*
from t
where (client_id, date_of_purchase) in (select client_id, max(date_of_purchase)
                                        from t
                                        group by client_id
                                       );
```

Of course, there are many ways to express similar logic . . . using `=` with a correlated subquery, `exists`, or `join` with an aggregation query.